# Insert images under correlating citations

Tags: image, ms-word, insert, find

My company has multiple standard PPT presentations that all have a Word doc of the presenter's notes to go along with them. The presenter's notes currently have slide icons on the left margin across from the paragraphs where the presenter is supposed to advance to the next slide. The icons are all numbered with a hashtag and the slide number (#13). Now they want to replace all the slide icons with images of the actual slides. Luckily, PPT automatically numbers the images when it saves them as PNGs. So, the image that I need to replace the slide icon #13 is Slide 13.PNG. Is there a way to use VBA to find the hashtags and numbers in the Word doc, then go to the saved file and find that same number and insert that image on the line under the hashtag? It would save a ridiculous number of hours of mind-numbing tedium. Thanks for any help you can give!